# Java EE 6 and JAXRPCSecurity

Tags: osgi, jax-ws, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I'am trying convert my Java EE 5 (GlassFish v2, Metro 2.1.1) application to Java EE 6 (GlassFish 3.1.2, Metro 2.2.1-1). I have problem with webservice client, which security is based on JAXRPCSecuirty. JAXRPCSecurity configuration:

```
private final static String SECURITY_CONFIG =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> "+
    "<xwss:JAXRPCSecurity xmlns:xwss=\"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config\">                " +
    "   <xwss:Service>                                                                          " +
    "       <xwss:SecurityConfiguration dumpMessages=\"true\">                      " +
    "           <xwss:Sign includeTimestamp=\"false\">                                          " +
    "               <xwss:X509Token certificateAlias=\"certificate_alias\" />                       " +
    "               <xwss:CanonicalizationMethod disableInclusivePrefix=\"true\" />             " + 
    "               <xwss:SignatureTarget type=\"xpath\" value=\"//SOAP-ENV:Body\">             " +
    "                 <xwss:Transform algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"     " +
    "                                 disableInclusivePrefix=\"true\" />                        " +
    "               </xwss:SignatureTarget>                                                     " +
    "           </xwss:Sign>                                                                    " +
    "       </xwss:SecurityConfiguration>                                                       " +
    "   </xwss:Service>                                                                         " +
    "   <xwss:SecurityEnvironmentHandler>                                                       " +
    "      SecurityCallbackHandler                                                              " +
    "   </xwss:SecurityEnvironmentHandler>                                                      " +
    "</xwss:JAXRPCSecurity>";
```

And how I set this configuration to webservice client:

```
public void configureSecurity() throws SITAWebServiceException {        
    String JAXRPCSecurityXML = completeJAXRPCSecurityXML(alias, keyStore, callbackHandler, dumpMessage);

    byte[] JAXRPCSecurityXMLBytes = convertJAXRPSecurityXMLToBytes(JAXRPCSecurityXML);

    XWSSecurityConfiguration sc = createXWSSecurityConfiguration(JAXRPCSecurityXMLBytes);

    ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(XWSSecurityConfiguration.MESSAGE_SECURITY_CONFIGURATION, sc);      
}

private XWSSecurityConfiguration createXWSSecurityConfiguration(final byte[] JAXRPCSecurityXML) throws SITAWebServiceException {
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(JAXRPCSecurityXML);
    try {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(is);
    } catch (XWSSecurityException e) {
        throw new SITAWebServiceException("XWSSecurityConfiguration problem.", e);
    } finally {
        closeInputStream(is);
    }
}
```

With GlassFish v2 and Metro 2.1.1, everything works fine. But GlassFish 3 uses OSGi based Metro (webservices-api-osgi and webservice-osgi) and classes from package *com.sun.xml.xwss* are no longer visible (isn't exproted) so I constantly get this Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/xwss/XWSSecurityConfiguration
```

Is there some solution how export package *com.sun.xml.xwss* or way how to change JAXRPCSecurity to something other/better?

Thanks.